# How do I calculate the $v^2$ part of the air resistance $(1/2)CpA$ into constants that will fit my general equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, drag

I am currently working on an applied maths project in which I have modeled the forces at play when a rollercoaster travels down a slope and comes to a stop over a distance $d$ with the use of brakes. For my final challenge I need to figure out the force applied by the brakes when the rollercoaster is on the flat plane. I managed to get a final velocity of the rollercoaster before the brakes are applied i.e. before the slope becomes flat. However I am so stuck for the final equation, being the force applied. I can’t wrap my head around what I need to do in order to display the $v^2$ in the air resistance equation as constants that can be displayed in a graph of Force vs. Height. This is the start of my final equation
$(1/2)mv^2 = dma$ (the force applied by brakes) $+\ddot{u}mgd$ (the friction force) + $(1/2)CdpAv^2$.
I’m aware that the $v^2$ at the start and end of the equation are not the same. I think I have to display the $v^2$ as a function of time but I do not know where to start. Any help?